# Foreach loop will not read XML

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.5, xelement

I am trying to read some data from an XML. I am using the same code in another application with an almost identical XML layout which seems to work..
But I cannot get any of the code to run inside the foreach loop with this code:

It seems to read the XML ok if If have a breakpoint and view _xml.Elements

```
 XElement value in _xml.Elements("effects").Elements("effect")
```

C#

```
 XElement _xml = XElement.Load("Effects.xml");
                {
                    foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("effects").Elements("effect"))
                    {
                       //will not execute any code in here.
                        DVOXML _item = new DVOXML();
                        _item.Name = value.Element("name").Value;
                        _item.Param = value.Element("params").Value;


                    }
                }
```

XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <effects>
   <effect>
    <name>effect1</name>
    <params>xmldata</params>
  </effect>
  <effect>
    <name>effect2</name>
    <params>xmldata</params>
  </effect>
</effects>
```

Comment: Just to check - you're sure that `value` contains the XML and is loaded, right?  You should be able to debug through it and check easily by hovering your mouse over it.

Comment: I think your problem might be that you're not looking at the root - try `_xml.Root.Elements("effect")` and let me know if that works.  It's likely not executing any code because you are getting 0 items back from your LINQ-XML query.

Comment: @Phoenixblade9 value is indeed empty. And there is no _xml.Root extention method

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to using XDocument rather than XElement - let me whip something up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case effects is the root.

Use this:

```
foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("effect"))
{
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include "effects" in your query - that's already the root.  Just use this as your query:

```
foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("effect"))
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ox3D73) demonstrating that it works.

Comment: :) indeed.  I try to include a .NET Fiddle with my answers whenever possible, usually means I'm a bit later, oh well

Comment: Hold one.. it works if I read from the xml.parse text, but it wont work if I load from my file with the same text: XElement _xml = XElement.Load("Effects.xml");

Comment: @DanSewell your xml file would need to be in the same location as the assembly for that to work.  Otherwise you need an absolute path.  `C:/myfile.xml` or something similar

Comment: Ok, sorted it. VS seemed to be looking at a different XML file than I told it to. odd. Deleted things, then re-added and it worked. thanks.